# What is the benefit of a Fermentap kettle

Tags: kettle

I've seen a number of kettle add-ons and am just wondering what the benefits are? I saw a Hot Liquor Tank, false bottoms, etc.. I'm just interested in learning all I can. I currently just have a basic 8 gallon pot.

In particular something like [this](http://moreflavor-pavinthewaysoftw.netdna-ssl.com/product_image/morebeer/232x240/7000.jpg).

Comment: Is there a specific add-on you want information about? Perhaps you could add a link to show what you're considering. Hot liquor tanks are separate vessels entirely, and false bottoms are used in mash tuns.  As it stands though, the question is very broad and a bit hard to understand.

Comment: sorry, so i guess my real question is what is a fermentap for? i asked the elaborated questions as a side thought i guess.

Comment: http://moreflavor-pavinthewaysoftw.netdna-ssl.com/product_image/morebeer/232x240/7000.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The kettle you linked to has has two drilled holes into which are fitted [weld-less bulkheads](https://www.google.com/search?q=weldless+bulkhead&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=sEETVerdCNPaoATBjoL4BQ&ved=0CC4QsAQ&biw=1280&bih=608). The bottom one has a ball valve attached to it, allowing you to empty the kettle from there (instead of picking up the whole thing and pouring, or siphoning the liquid out). The top is plugged but would usually hold a thermometer.

The benefits of add-ons depend entirely on what you plan to do with it as they tend to be specific to a particular purpose (i.e. mash tuns need a false bottom to allow wort separation and a thermometer to monitor temperature, while a kettle may only need the bottom valve for emptying).

Comment: so pretty much its convenience? and maybe trying to keep oxygen out?

Comment: Yeah, pretty much just convenience. Oxygen exclusion hasn't got much role to play here.